# Haskell typing for Int's and Double's

Tags: haskell, typing

Just quick question about typing.

If I type into ghci `:t [("a",3)]` I get back `[("a",3)] :: Num t => [([Char], t)]`

Inside a file I have defined a type as:

```
type list = [(String, Int)]
```

How can I change the type to support both `Int`s and `Double`s with the type I have defined, similar to what I wrote in ghci?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have an error in your code. Data types must start with capital letters:

```
type List = [(String, Int)]
```

(Note that `String` is a type synonym for `[Char]`, i.e. they are exactly the same type). We'll solve your problem in a roundabout way. Note that you can make the type completely general in the second slot of the tuple:

```
type List a = [(String,a)]
```

so that your type parameterizes over arbitrary types. If you need to specialize to numeric types in some function, then you can make that specialization for each function individually. For example:

```
foo :: Num a => List a
foo = [("Hello",1),("World",2)]
```

We could have included a constraint in the data type, like this:

```
data Num a => List a = List [(String,a)]
```

but you would still have to include the constraint `Num a => ...` in every function declaration, so you don't actually save any typing. For this reason, Haskell programmers generally follow the rule "Don't include type constraints in data declarations."

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. I'll accept the answer in a few mins.

Comment: Note that `DataTypeContexts` are gone in Haskell2010. You can still have them with a GHC extension, but why would one, they never were useful anyway.

Comment: One last thing, I have a function that checks if two numbers are equal in a list, using the contraint Num a => gives me an error of could not deduce (Eq a) from a use of '=='.

To fix this I changed the constraint to Eq a => ... Is this the best way to do it, as I would need to add the Eq a => constraint to a lot of my functions.

Comment: It *should* work with with the constraint `Num a => ...` since a `Num` instance depends on you already having defined an `Eq` instance. For example, the code `f :: Num a => a -> Bool` (line 1) and `f x = x == x` (line 2) works fine for me. What compiler/interpreter are you using, and what version?

Comment: I'm using the latest release from here:
http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/windows.html

Comment: If it's definitely not working, I suggest that you create a new question about it, and include all the relevant information (including haskell version, the code that gives the error, and the full error message you receive.)

Comment: In the latest GHC, `Num` doesn't include `Eq` anymore, so you need to have both constraints in your signature if you do both comparisons and arithmetic. I.e. `f :: (Num a, Eq a) => ...`

Comment: Ok, I'll try to get it to compile it first if not I post it here. Thanks.